# Image is Clickable, without no hyperlink case surrounded

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, interface

How to remove the clickabilty of an image?

as you may see, there is no  arroung the image...

the code of img:

```
<input name="ui_taskFormControl$ctl03$ctl00$ctl03$ui_BirthPlaceImage" height="20" id="ui_taskFormControl_ctl03_ctl00_ctl03_ui_BirthPlaceImage" type="image" src="SmartPenHandler.ashx?FormId=XYZ&FieldId=BirthPlace" complete="complete"/>
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f11efd474.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9f11efd474.jpg)

Comment: private HtmlInputImage ui_BirthPlaceImage; 
The input is initialized like that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ui_BirthPlaceImage.Disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

An `<input>` of type image is a form of form submit button. If you want an image that isn't clickable just use the good old fashioned `<img>` tag. There are probably other ways if you want it to stay as an `<input>` but using `<img>` will be your easiest solution.

Comment: private HtmlInputImage ui_BirthPlaceImage; 
The input is initialized like that above. How can I  achieve in this style of work?

Comment: Example Code:
<input type="button" name=myButton value="disable" disabled>

how can make it disbaled on c#

ref:http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html/form-button.php?myImgButton.x=32&myImgButton.y=9&myImgButton=HAI

Comment: @blgnklc: Do you need it to be an <input> that is disabled rather than an <img> then? If an Image is fine the object you want is an HtmlImage.

Comment: I have found my answer:    ui_SmartPenFieldImage.Disabled = true;

thanks sir!